# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SFrame'

Tags: python, graphlab

I am taking ML course in Coursera and I have installed GraphLab Create and ipython notebook.I am new to ML and python.

I get the following error,

```
import graphlab
sf = graphlab.SFrame('people-example.csv')
```

> AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
>
> ----> 1 sf = graphlab.SFrame('people-example.csv')
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SFrame'

How do I fix this error?I have the people-example.csv in the correct path and no spelling mistake on SFrame
Any help is greatly appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: You most likely have a file called `graphlab.py`. Rename it and remove any associated .pyc file and try again.

Comment: I don't have any file named graphlab.py.Thanks!

Comment: Thanks bernie, that was the issue which I had, though I read your comment after I resolved it and came here to post the solution and discovered your tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the library `graphlab` is updated and works with your current python version. Changes on built-in libraries from python 2x to 3x are likely to cause issues like this one.

Comment: Thank you very much.Initially,I got an error when I ran import graphlab stating that I need to give write permission to the folder that had graphlab and to run graphlab.get_dependencies() .By running this function you agree to the following licenses. 
* libstdc++ : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/license.html
*xz:http://git.tukani.org/?p=xz.git

I just unchecked the readonly option for the graphlab folder.I tried to run import graphlab and there were no errors.But I was getting the attribute error for the next one; sf = graphlab.SFrame.read_csv('people-example.csv')

Comment: The fix was simple.I had to run the graphlab.get_dependencies().I got the following,
downloading xz
extracting xz and I had to close and restart ipython.

Everthing is find now.Appreciate all your replies.Thank you!!!

Comment: No worries. I suggest you to answer your own question and then mark it as the valid answer so it doesn't keep appearing on the unanwsered ones. (My english sucks today).

Answer (score 24):

In your iPython/Jupyter notebook follow these steps in this particular order.

1. This will download and install dependencies. `graphlab.get_dependencies()`
2. Restart Kernel : 
   `Kernel > Restart`
3. Now import graphlab: `import graphlab`
4. `sf = graphlab.SFrame('people-example.csv')`

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: I ran this `graphlab.get_dependencies()` in notebook but got an issue. `NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a54c2104129b> in <module>()
      1 #import graphlab
----> 2 graphlab.get_dependencies()

NameError: name 'graphlab' is not defined`

Answer (score 4):

At first, you should run:

```
import graphlab
graphlab.product_key.set_product_key('your product key here')
```

where `product_key` is a key you received to your email after registering on turi.com with your Coursera credentials.

After this operation everything's going to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart the ipython kernel on your iPython/Jupyter notebook for graphlab to see the dependencies in the correct locations.

menu options:

`Kernel > Restart`

and try again. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I followed these steps.

1.Restart kernel

2.`import graphlab`

3.`sf = graphlab.SFrame('people-example.csv')`

Then it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Change it to:

```
sf = graphlab.SFrame.read_csv('people-example.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you.I changed to sf = graphlab.SFrame.read_csv('people-example.csv') and still get the same error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a961fb2bed33> in <module>()
----> 1 sf = graphlab.SFrame.read_csv('people-example.csv')

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SFrame'

Answer (score -2):

ok i was having the same problem today and no one can help me ... but i finally found the solution of this problem .... first when you write the code make sure of some important thing 
1- s an f in sframe must be capital 
2- the most important when you writing  people-example.csv   write first 4 letters and hit ((tap)) it will continue the word . and here you are every thing is ok :)